# Use of Process with using block

Tags: c#, process, coding-style, idisposable, using-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens if I don't close a System.Diagnostics.Process in my C# console app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185314/what-happens-if-i-dont-close-a-system-diagnostics-process-in-my-c-console-app)

As `System.Diagnostics.Process` inherits from `Component` which implements `IDisposable`, should I always create a `Process` with a `using` block?

For example, this...:

```
using (var process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "some process.exe";
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

...instead of this:

```
var process = new Process
    { 
        StartInfo = { FileName = "some process.exe" }
    };
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

I ask because I've rarely seen `Process` appear in a `using` block; for example the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) for `Process` does not use it. Having the use of the object initializer is helpful too.

If I *should* be using it, should I then go and 'retrofit' it to my existing codebase?

What might be the consequences if this were not done? (Assuming `WaitForExit()` is being called correctly in each case.)

Comment: Thanks - hadn't seen this question. I agree it's similar, but I am specifically asking about Dispose() rather than Close().

Comment: But the accepted answer there is better than any other here... :P

Comment: "Having the use of the object initializer is helpful too." You can still use the object initializer even if using a `using` block. I know the question is quite old, but I tested this with .NET 2.0 and it works fine at least that far back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't or cannot use using(), you should make sure you Dispose the process variable when it is no longer needed.

If you use the process variable in a class (instead of a Program or a method), then that class should implement IDisposable and then call _process.Dispose in its Dispose(bool) method:

```
void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    ...
    if (_process != null)
    {
        Dispose(_process);
    }
}
```

If there is no _process field but only a process variable that you use in your method, you must dispose of it inside the method:

```
void MyMethod()
{
    var process = ...
    ... use it here ...
    process.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: That's the general rule, but the OP asks about specific information regarding `System.Diagnostics.Process`.

Comment: And I say that, also in the case of Process, the rule applies.

Comment: @rsenna - You're right, however, making this rule explicit may help others who aren't aware of why using() should be used in this case.

Answer (score 4):

The MSDN example is contrived. The program which opens a process handle is exiting as soon as it starts the process. When that program exits, any handles it opened are closed.

If you open a process handle, you should close it. The Process.Dispose override of Component.Dispose simply calls Process.Close. The using statement simplifies this.