# Does a command-line process need to be closed after exiting

Tags: c#

I'm using ffprobe.exe to get info about video file.

```
Process probe = new Process();
probe.StartInfo.FileName = "\"" + ffmpegFolder + "ffprobe.exe\"";
probe.StartInfo.Arguments = "-select_streams v -show_entries stream=duration \"" + path + name + "\"";
probe.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
probe.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
probe.Start();
string s = probe.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
probe.WaitForExit();
```

Do I need to call `probe.Close()` after process exits?

Comment: Also look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857893/use-of-process-with-using-block

Comment: Thank you. I will always call Close() after a process exits.